# How can i add the UIbutton's text which comes from the database

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to create app for iOS through Xcode.I created the`UIButton` through user interface and i want to add the`UIButton` text which it should get from database.

I need to use text and total count of user information stored in database.Total count should automatically updated.I don't want the notification circle on a `UIButton`.

some one please help me and this question for xcode-iOS.

Comment: can u show some sample how do u need the answer

Comment: Edit your question and add your code, to see what you have done. Show us the look and fell you have now. and more or less what you want... (if you can't post a image, upload to a server and post it in a comment, someone will add your picture to your questioon)

Comment: @saifubzone You take the value from database and store it in NSString and assign that string to UIButton as text.

Comment: @saifubzone if you want to add screen shot . you can add it into your question. there is image option. You can give path there. or select your image.

Comment: guys am new to this and i tried to upload images but it asking 10 reputation to post image.i don't know 10 reputation about image

Comment: @AshokLondhe: Thanks for your help, one more thing that if database updates the value will used in the string also update?

Comment: @saifubzone Values in the database updates only when you update your database or done any change in that.

Comment: @saifubzone Which database your using.?

Comment: @AshokLondhe Mysql database

Comment: @AshokLondhe: Thanks I got idea...

Comment: @saifubzone so how to access the data.. using web service or anything else.?

Comment: i tried like this with label couldnt try with button's text.

Comment: through web service @AshokLondhe

Comment: @saifubzone k. what happens with button..

Comment: @saifubzone i have posted answer try this and reply me.

Comment: @AshokLondhe:thanks for code, i skipped that question and will be done this code later

Comment: @saifubzone K. fine but if my answer help you please check it as a accepted answer.

Comment: @saifubzone hi... you have not replied. i am trying to help you .

Comment: @AshokLondhe:sorry bro actually am currently working on other thing and i couldn't try this time because am bzy with some other work,if i checked this i will give check mark. i think it will work .

Comment: @saifubzone it works perfectly. so i think no need to hesitate. After all its your decision.

Comment: @AshokLondhe:if its work perfectly then i don't need more code for this and thanks lot for your valuable time spend for me and surely i will work this code in future brooo

Answer (score 0):

To Set the Text or Title on Button...

```
 NSString *yourString=@"XYZ"; // The string which you want to set on button.
[self.btn1 setTitle:yourString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```